# How do I create file with json inside?

Tags: json, typescript, file

I'm trying to create a `new File()` and write json to it but I Don't really understand how to.
I've looked at the documentation but I don't understand what BlobPart is.

When I tried this:

```
const file = new File(this.myFrom.getRawValue(), 'json');
```

I got error :

```
Failed to construct 'File': The object must have a callable @@iterator property.
```

I need to append the file to formData like this:

```
formData.append('file', file);
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a browser, or in server-side nodeJS?

Comment: I just need to append a file to formData because that's what my server requires

Comment: I see. I suggest maybe using a Blob instead (the formData accepts a Blob, and File is just a subclass of Blob). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob - it has an example specifically of adding JSON text to it. Remember it has to be passed in within an array.

Comment: P.S. Any reason you don't just change your form to include a normal file input, then the user can create a file on their device and just find it using the file control? It wasn't clear what kind of input your JSON is coming from.

Comment: I tried using blob but the server responded with: not a .json file.

I have a reactive form that will create a json that I need to upload to the server but the server need a file :/

Comment: P.S. As per the documentation, the File() constructor also expects an Array. Did you try with something like `const file = new File([this.myFrom.getRawValue()], 'json');`?

Comment: For some reason I got response: not a json file even tough I specifies the type

Comment: `even tough I specifies the type`...where did you specify the type? I don't see that. All you've done is pass in the data and the name. Type can be specified in one of the options, but you haven't provided any options - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

Comment: Sorry, I specified it like this: `const file = new File([this.configForm.getRawValue()], 'payapp_init_json.json', {type : 'application/json'});`

Comment: Ok thanks. So what's still missing in order for us to really get the full picture here is a) the exact content returned by getRawValue(), b) the code which generates and sends the AJAX request, and c) the server-side code which tries to process it.

Comment: I looked at the file that was sent and the inside of the file was just: `[object Object]`. I've downloaded the file and the inside text is: `[object Object]`

Comment: It _probably_ indicates that you need to use JSON.stringify on the output of getRawValue() ...but that's just a guess since you didn't confirm what its content or type is yet.

Comment: The correct syntax was: `const file = new File([JSON.stringify(this.configForm.getRawValue())], 'payapp_init_json.json', {type: 'application/json'});`. If you put is an answer I can mark it as correct because you helped me solve it.

Comment: Done - see below. Glad we could get it resolved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly right. You just need to

a) put the content inside an array, as per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

b) set the content type through the options

This is the corrected version of the code:

```
const file = new File([JSON.stringify(this.configForm.getRawValue())], 'payapp_init_json.json', {type: 'application/json'});
```